# how to restrict an input in c

Tags: c, input, int, restriction

I want to prevent my program from any other types of input instead of int. How to check the type of an input without assigning it to a variable? in C

Comment: What form of input are you talking about? Input from the console? Input from a file? Input over the network?

Answer (score 3):

See [strtod](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strtod/), [strtol](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strtol/) and friends.

All of those function take an out parameter (generally referred to as `endptr`) which shows you where the conversion ended. You can use that information to decide if the input you wanted to convert was an integer or floating point number or not a number at all.

The strategy is to try to parse the input as a base 10 long. If that does not work (i.e. if there were unconverted characters), see if parsing it as a double works. If neither works, the input is not a number. Clearly, you would have to decide what basic type you would want to use for numbers. You can build in more checks and refinements, but here is a simple example.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct a_number {
    unsigned char is_long;
    union {
        double d;
        long i;
    };
};

int main(void) {
    int n;
    char *input_strings[3] = {
        "1234","1234.56", "12asdf"
    };

    struct a_number *numbers[3];

    for (n = 0; n < 3; ++n) {
        char *start = input_strings[n];
        char *end;
        long i = strtol(start, &end, 10);
        if ( *end == '\0' ) {
            struct a_number *num = malloc(sizeof(*num));
            assert( num );
            num->is_long = 1;
            num->i = i;
            numbers[n] = num;
        }
        else {
            double d = strtod(start, &end);
            if ( *end == '\0' ) {
                struct a_number *num = malloc(sizeof(*num));
                assert( num );
                num->is_long = 0;
                num->d = d;
                numbers[n] = num;
            }
            else {
                numbers[n] = NULL;
            }
        }
    }

    for (n = 0; n < 3; ++n) {
        if ( numbers[n] ) {
            if ( numbers[n]->is_long ) {
                printf("%ld\n", numbers[n]->i );
            }
            else {
                printf("%g\n", numbers[n]->d );
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should put it into a char variable (or a string) check it's validity, and then put it to the int var.
you have to read the data to somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Without assigning the input to a variable you cannot possibly do this.